# How to add decimal numbers within string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to ask a user for an equation (such as 12.3 + 12.6) and returning "12.3 + 12.6 = 24.9"
So far my code looks like:

```
FinalEquation = 0
Equation = input("Please enter an equation:")
if "+" in Equation:
    FinalEquation = sum(float(n) for n in Equation.split() if n.isdigit())
print(Equation,"=",FinalEquation)
```

but it only works for integers and not numbers with decimals

Comment: If you want to support arbitrary syntax within the bounds of a specific language you define, then you want to write a parser. There are lots of (good) parser generators for Python; see https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing

Comment: (Of course, you can hand-code something yourself, but if you want automatic handling for precedence rules and such -- for instance, recognizing that `1 + 2 * 3` runs the multiplication first; or correctly parsing `( (1 * 2) + 3) * 4)` -- that'll get hairy).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I disagree with your last statement. Writing an expression parser by hand which handles operator precedence correctly is not that difficult. See _[Simple Top-Down Parsing in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm)_ and _[Parsing expressions by precedence climbing](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/02/parsing-expressions-by-precedence-climbing)_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, I meant _not that_ difficult ;-) In fact, I've written a few before myself.

Comment: Ahh. Keep in mind that my comment was directed to the OP, and using a difficulty scale appropriate to someone asking the question at hand -- implying not just the explicitly-stated lack of familiarity with the language, but also a lack of familiarity with compiler theory &c (as someone who'd taken a compiler design class or otherwise been through 200-level CSCI would have known where to start on their own).

Comment: @MYGz, of course there are lots of ways to cheat. But they'd get you a 0 if you turned them in in class. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ahh,I see what you mean. I guess I assumed that the OP knew their target language fairly well.

Comment: @MYGz, ...the requirement also calls for "operand space operator space operand" -- so at minimum should check that the first and last arguments are valid operands, and that the middle is a valid operator.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This needs to be closed, or eval/exec answers would keep pouring :D

Comment: As a note irrelevant to a class project, and not a guaranteed feature of CPython, just an implementation detail, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can actually evaluate basic addition with literals, and unlike `eval`, it's safe; it can't execute wholly arbitrary code. For example, `ast.literal_eval('42 + 27')` produces the integer value `69`.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way for what you're trying to do would probably be to just use the python `eval()` builtin. Some might may say its not a great idea to use eval() but it seems like it'd be appropriate what you're trying to do

```
user_input = "42 + 23"
print("{} = {}".format(user_input, eval(user_input)))
```

Comment: There'll always be a user who can't wait to have `__import__('shutil').rmtree(<some-path>, True)` evaluated